# Calcular la variación porcentual con respecto al mes anterior

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas, porcentaje

Mi base de datos posee información de un servicio de taxis. Necesito crear una sentencia en codigo sql (estoy trabajando con mysql) que determine la variacion porcentual en el número de servicios registrados con respecto al mes anterior.

Tengo la columna que es de tipo fecha: "tpep_pickup_datetime" y tiene el siguiente formato 2020-01-01 00:33:03.

Como en el primer mes no hay con quien comparar el resultado debe ser NULL en la columna "variacion_mes_anterior", esto no se como hacerlo.

La sentencia de codigo que estoy utilizando y que no me funciona es:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tpep_pickup_datetime, '%Y-%m') as mes, COUNT(id) as servicios,
CONCAT(
( SELECT TRUNCATE((count(test.id)/count(t.id) -1) *100, 0)
  FROM test AS t
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t.tpep_pickup_datetime, '%Y-%m')
 LIMIT 1
) , "%") as variacion_mes_anterior
FROM test
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tpep_pickup_datetime, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(tpep_pickup_datetime, '%Y-%m');
```

ejemplo:

| id | tpep_pickup_datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-01 00:33:03 |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 00:33:03 |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 00:33:03 |
| 3 | 2020-02-01 00:33:03 |
| 4 | 2020-02-02 00:33:03 |
| 5 | 2020-02-03 00:33:03 |
| 6 | 2020-02-04 00:33:03 |

Esto seria lo esperado por una sentencia de sql valida para mi problema

| mes | servicios | variacion_mes_anterior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 3 | NULL |
| 2020-02 | 4 | 33% |

Comment: ¿Qué versión de mySQL estás utilizando?

Comment: @jachguate gracias ya pude resolver con otra consulta

Comment: @Marcos perfecto ahora mismo lo hago

Answer (score 1):

La idea es hacer `LEFT JOIN` con el periodo anterior. Ten cuidado al calcular enero; la función `period_add()` puede ser útil.

En MySQL 8:

```
WITH periodos as (
  SELECT year(tpep_pickup_datetime)*100
        +month(tpep_pickup_datetime) periodo
       , count(1) conteo
    FROM test 
    GROUP BY periodo
)
SELECT p.periodo
     , p.conteo
     , (p.conteo/pa.conteo-1)*100 variacion
  FROM periodos p
    LEFT JOIN periodos pa
      ON pa.periodo = period_add(p.periodo,-1)
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder a la consulta. Intente probar con este codigo y no me devuelve lo que espero

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la consulta que me ayudó a resolver la pregunta inicial.

```
SELECT mes, 
       servicios, 
       CONCAT(ROUND(100 * (servicios / LAG(servicios) OVER (ORDER BY mes) - 1)), '%') variacion_mes_anterior
FROM ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tpep_pickup_datetime, '%Y-%m') mes,
              COUNT(*) servicios
       FROM test1
       GROUP BY mes ) subquery
ORDER BY mes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Con `LEFT JOIN` podrias lograr esto. Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT t1.year, t1.month, t1.servicios, ((t2.servicios-t1.servicios)/t1.servicios)*100 as porciento
FROM (SELECT YEAR(tpep_pickup_datetime) as year, MONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime) as month, count(id) as servicios
        FROM test
        GROUP BY YEAR(tpep_pickup_datetime), MONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime),
        ORDER BY YEAR(tpep_pickup_datetime), MONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime)) as t1 
    LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT YEAR(tpep_pickup_datetime) as year, MONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime) as month, count(id) as servicios
        FROM test
        GROUP BY YEAR(tpep_pickup_datetime), MONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime),
        ORDER BY YEAR(tpep_pickup_datetime), MONTH(tpep_pickup_datetime)) as t2 
    ON t1.year = t2.year AND t1.month = t2.month - 1
ORDER BY t1.year, t1.month;
```